# How to query nearby addresses during reverse geocoding request

Tags: geocoding, reverse-geocoding, bing-maps

How do I find all the addresses in a small search radius for a specific geocode point? I want to display a user 5-10 address that he can pick from based on geolocation data I retrieve from his phone. I'm using Bing maps location API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx), but open to other APIs if this doesn't work. The documentation talks about BoundingBox as a supported location type but I'm unable to use when I tried.

Answer (score 0):

The reverse geocoder will usually only return one location. Bounding boxes are not supported for reverse geocoding. To do what you are looking to do you will need to make multiple reverse geocoder requests over an area. I put together a code sample a few years back on how to do this using Silverlight. You should be able to see the logic in there and migrate it over to use the REST services and what ever programming language you are using.You can find the blog post here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/reverse-geocoding-over-a-search-area/